# Location Tracking Persistence

Tags: swift

If I have location tracking subbed out to a separate class, how many times do I need to call it? Is it persistent, or do I need to reinitialize the class in every separate view controller the user visits?

Based on my testing, it seems to maintain a persistent state, but I'm unsure and don't want to make promises I can't keep in production.

Comment: I need it to be running even if the app is in the background.

Comment: I'm thinking Singleton, but what about dependency injection? Singleton preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two completely different questions here:

1. If you want a single location manager class instance available from throughout the app, all you need to make sure is that you keep a reference to it somewhere. You can use a singleton. Or you can just establish some strong reference to it early on in the process and simply pass along references to it.

   You asked:

   > I'm thinking Singleton, but what about dependency injection? Singleton preferred?

   Dependency injection (DI) is really useful when it’s critical to be able reason about when the state of a particular shared object may mutate, using DI to make this contract explicit. It’s also very useful in unit testing, where you want to inject particular test data or stub some interface.

   In this case, though, I'm assuming you're just providing some mechanism to inquire regarding the device location (and possibly offer other location-based services). I might not say it’s the “preferred” solution, but a singleton certainly would be a very reasonable approach.
2. Regarding your goal of trying to keep track of location after the user leaves the app, you should be aware that running this from Xcode does change the app lifecycle, preventing the app from being suspended or, eventually, terminated. You may want to install the app on a physical device. You can then disconnect from Xcode and test the true app lifecycle. (I often rely upon [unified logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) as outlined in 2016’s [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) or 2020’s [Explore logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/) so that I can watch device log statements on my macOS console while not attached to Xcode.)

   I assume that this is not a true navigation app (i.e., the user is in a vehicle, the device is connected to power and the app will keep running in the background), but rather you just want to [handle location events in the background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background). In such case, consider the [visits location service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_visits_location_service), [significant change location service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service), region monitoring, etc.

But the lifespan of the location manager object while the app runs (e.g. the choice of singleton or single instance passed around or multiple instances) and the correct handling of events while the app isn't running are two completely different and unrelated questions.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is wrap the location manager in a class and initialize it once — no need for formal singleton — and keep that instance in a persistence object, such as the app delegate or the root view controller:

```
class ManagerHolder {
    let locman = CLLocationManager()
    var doThisWhenAuthorized : (() -> ())?
    func checkForLocationAccess(always:Bool = false, andThen f: (()->())? = nil) {
        // no services? fail but try get alert
        guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else {
            print("no location services")
            self.locman.startUpdatingLocation()
            return
        }
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            if always { // try to step up
                self.doThisWhenAuthorized = f
                self.locman.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            } else {
                f?()
            }
        case .authorizedAlways:
            f?()
        case .notDetermined:
            self.doThisWhenAuthorized = f
            always ?
                self.locman.requestAlwaysAuthorization() :
                self.locman.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // do nothing
            break
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
            // do nothing, or beg the user to authorize us in Settings
            break
        @unknown default: fatalError()
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {    
    let managerHolder = ManagerHolder()
    var locman : CLLocationManager {
        return self.managerHolder.locman
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        self.locman.delegate = self
    }
    // ...
}
```